# WPF Hide Grid Column

Tags: wpf, grid

I have a xaml grid defined as:

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

The first column will contain a TextBlock and the second column a TextBox for data capture.
How can I toggle the visibility of first column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to change the width of the first column to "Auto". Then I set up the bindings of my first textbox so that its Visibility property was set to Collapsed (not hidden) which results in the column not being rendered.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ColumnDefinition>
       <ColumnDefinition.Style>
             <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                 <Setter Property="Width" Value="*" />
                     <Style.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsColumnVisible}" Value="False">
                             <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
                         </DataTrigger>
                      </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
         </ColumnDefinition.Style>
    </ColumnDefinition>
```

Please do implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel